# Retrieve content from custom tab in app

Tags: android, callback, chrome-custom-tabs

After searching for hours I have to ask: Is there a way to retreive the content from a chrome custom tab from the hosting activity in android?

My prefered way would be to start Chrome Custom Tabs from my App via *StartActivityForResult* and react in *OnActivityResult*. Until now I only managed to receive back the requestCode, but data is always null (and resultCode always canceled).

I've learned it would be possible by setting up a way through deep linking and pushing an intend defined via javascript on a website to a specific app handling exactly that deeplink uri schema (e.g. here: [Chrome Devs intents](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents)).

**But** this seem rather complicated for passing a *success* or *failed* back to the app after solving a task at the server.

**So**: Is there a way to put some data to the Chrome Tab passed back as result to the hosting Activity?

BTW: A side question: If I would use deep linking instead, wouldn't this mess up the "proper" lifecycles a bit? App->starts ChromeTab->starts Intent->starts App again?

Any hints are very apreciated!

Comment: Did not find a solution, so I now use the webpage shown in the custom tab to call a server-sided save script and start an api call to fetch that data once the OnActivityResult is raised.

Comment: I would still be interested if there is another, more direct way - so if anyone has an idea...?

Comment: Anything new since then ?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not.